# PowerBuilder: How to reconnect To DB files (.pb) after reinstalling OS and PB

Tags: powerbuilder

I recently reinstalled OS and reinstalled PB 10.5. I am trying to open saved works like workSpace, .pbl, pbt But not able to reconnect saved Pb data base file (.pb), which is in the same folder.
How to include and connect DataBase File for the same sample.

Comment: Have you installed a database? what about the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the database file .db (not .pb)?

The database software must be installed first. If it is .db then it is likely SQL Anywhere.

You'll need to create an ODBC profile for it in the ODBC Admin, then a DB Profile in PowerBuilder.

Comment: My HardDisk Broke again because of which i have to re-install os and pb for the second time. Last time i stored a .ini file in the same folder in which is my project. On connect to the profile the following error is shown "data source name not found and no default driver specified."

Comment: Yes it is .db file. what you mean by database software. where can i learn small sample projects to understand database application. Regards

Comment: When you install PowerBuilder it also gives you the option to install SQL Anywhere. That is probably the database software you need. Once everything is installed, you will have to recreate the ODBC profile and then create a database profile in PowerBuilder that uses the ODBC profile to connect to the database.